# detect concentric circles in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

HI i m trying to detect concentric circles in drilled aluminum sheet

[image]

below is the code which I'm using but it not detecting inner circle or outer circle. can anyone please help

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("/Users/n/Downloads/New_Images/crop5.jpeg",0)

output = cv2.imread("/Users/n/Downloads/New_Images/crop5.jpeg",1)
cv2.imshow("Original image", image)
cv2.waitKey()

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(11,11),0)

cv2.imshow("Blurred image", blurred)
cv2.waitKey()
setItem=set()
previous=0;
minR=4
for maxR in range(9,300,9):
    # Finds circles in a grayscale image using the Hough transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100,
                             param1=100,param2=100,minRadius=minR,maxRadius=maxR)
    minR+=4
    # cv2.HoughCircles function has a lot of parameters, so you can find more about it in documentation
    # or you can use cv2.HoughCircles? in jupyter nootebook to get that 

    # Check to see if there is any detection
    if circles is not None:
        # If there are some detections, convert radius and x,y(center) coordinates to integer
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            # Draw the circle in the output image
            cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0,255,0), 1)
            # Draw a rectangle(center) in the output image
            cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 2, y - 2), (x + 2, y + 2), (0,255,0), -1)
            setItem.add(r)

lst=sorted(setItem)
print("Length of List =", len(lst))
for item in lst:
    print(item)

cv2.imshow("Detections",output)
cv2.imwrite("CirclesDetection.jpg",output)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Please attach the current output and expected output ?

Comment: current output https://imgur.com/a/papfhPO

Comment: expected output https://imgur.com/8RUpqNh

Comment: @MaheshV blurring your image with kernel size of 11 will not help

Comment: different lighting could improve the situation. automated optical inspection always hinges on suitable lighting. your material is metal. it's reflective. you have to work with reflections.